# React native convert real time recording data to writable base64?

Tags: react-native, base64, audio-recording, chunks

I am recording audio using "react-native-recording" lib and get real time data as below format.

0,-1,0,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,1,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,1,-1,0,-1,0,-1,-5,-5,-4,-5,-4,-6,-8,-7,-7,-8,-7,-8,-10,-11,-10,-8,-7,-8,-7,-5,-4,-5,-4,-2,2,3,2,4,5,6,8,7,5,5,6,5,6,5,7,9,8,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,2,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,3,3,1,4,6,3,4,6,6,7,9,9,12,11,8,8,9,7,5,5,4,1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-3,-7,-8,-8,-9,-11,-11,-14,-15,-15,-17,-18,-18,-17,-18,-17,-18,-17,-18,-17,-18,-18,-13,-9,-11,-8,-5,-5,-4,-4,-5,-4,-1,3,6,5,7,12,12,13,13,10,8,9,6,7,8,4,2,3,0,-4,-5,-5,-7,-9,-12,-15,-15,-16,-18,-18,-17,-18,-17,-15,-14,-14,-15,-15,-13,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-8,-7,-8,-7,-10,-10,-7,-8,-10,-10,-11,-14,-16,-18,-20,-23,-25,-23,-23,-27,-26,-24,-27,-26,-23,-24,-27,-27,-28,-30,-29,-26,-28,-28,-24,-21,-21,-16,-13,-15,-12,-6,-4,-4,-2,1,-1,-1,3,1,0,2,3,2,2,3,1,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-3,-5,-5,-7,-6,-4,-7,-10,-9,-7,-6,-1,-1,-4,-2,0,0,2,3,2,3,3,4,6,5,4,0,0,2,3,3,2,0,0,3,2,-1,0,-1,-7,-9,-8,-11,-11,-9,-12,-15,-12,-9,-11,-11,-9,-8,-7,-8,-7,-4,-1,-1,0,2,2,4,5,6,11,14,12,15,18,19,22,25,27,29,31,33,38,42,42,43,45,42,41,43,40,38,41,40,33,32,33,30,28,29,26,26,29,27,26,25,23,20,18,16,16,13,7,6,5,6,5,3,1,-1,0,-1,1,3,3,2,4,5,3,3,6,2,0,0,-1,-4,-7,-8,-7,-7,-6,-4,-5,-4,-5,-4,-1,0,0,-1,-4,-4,-5,-7,-7,-8,-11,-11,-10,-11,-7,-4,-6,-8,-5,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,-4,-5,-5,-4,-2,1,3,2,3,3,5,6,4,3,5,6,4,3,1,-4,-8,-10,-14,-16,-18,-24,-22,-20,-21,-19,-16,-18,-18,-17,-20,-20,-20,-24,-29,-27,-27,-30,-36,-40,-41,-41,-40,-41,-42,-45,-47,-46,-47,-46,-49,-54,-59,-60,-62,-64,-68,-73,-78,-81,-79,-76,-77,-82,-82,-77,-74,-72,-70,-69,-69,-66,-63,-62,-58,-57,-57,-53,-49,-46,-42,-38,-36,-29,-21,-14,-7,-5,-1,8,16,18,19,23,28,29,29,35,38,39,43,47,52,57,60,64,67,68,67,70,69,63,58,54,49,41,31,21,12,3,-6,-10,-17,-26,-33,-40,-47,-52,-58,-65,-72,-80,-85,-90,-95,-99,-104,-109,-109,-108,-109,-106,-101,-95,-88,-84,-76,-65,-59,-53,-42,-35,-31,-25,-17,-9,0,9,20,32,41,51,64,76,86,95,104,112,118,125,130,129,131,132,132,133,132,133,135,137,140,142,144,149,153,155,159,163,161,161,162,161,162,161,154,147,143,139,134,129,125,118,112,107,100,91,81,72,64,53,41,30,16,3,-7,-17,-30,-43,-54,-62,-62,-62,-69,-78,-84,-88,-88,-89,-93,-102,-114,-120,-122,-123,-127,-137,-149,-154,-154,-154,-156,-163,-169,-170,-169,-162,-153,-153,-158,-156,-150,-141,-133,-127,-119,-111,-95,-68,-41,-17,13,46,83,132,181,223,266,311,350,389,427,455,474,492,506,520,530,528,518,510,503,492,474,447,407,364,322,277,227,168,97,23,-47,-115,-183,-251,-323,-391,-448,-497,-542,-583,-620,-651,-675,-691,-702,-715,-727,-734,-734,-727,-717,-710,-700,-683,-658,-629,-596,-563,-530,-497,-458,-414,-377

I want to convert it into base64 and then i want to write wav file from base64.

Comment: have you found any solution?